# Why is my JS Code for random color generator not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have an error in the console that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at (index):14

Here is my code to analyze:

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" />
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById('text'),
  randomColor = function(e) {
      var hex = Math.floor( Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF ),
          res = e.target,
          result = "#" + hex.toString(16);
      res.style.backgroundColor = result;
      res.innerHTML = result;
   };
div.addEventListener('mouseover', randomColor);
    </script>
    <style>
      #text{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: 'Quicksand';
    }
      body{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Quicksand';
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hover over me to get a random color!</h1>
    <div id="text">Hex code</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not understand because it works in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/talon4567/xb8tfqk1/12/). Someone please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stack snippet with your code but with the various css, js and html re-arranged.

In your original single html file, you should include your js after the html.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('text'),
  randomColor = function(e) {
    var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF),
      res = e.target,
      result = "#" + hex.toString(16);
    res.style.backgroundColor = result;
    res.innerHTML = result;
  };
div.addEventListener('mouseover', randomColor);
```

```css
#text {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" />

<h1>Hover over me to get a random color!</h1>
<div id="text">Hex code</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue with running the code in browser is that your script is in head tag, so its loading before the DOM. In Jsfiddle the script loads after the DOM. So you have to put the script Just before ending the `<body>` tag.

Its always better to wrap the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or (as suggested upper one is not required any more)

```
$(function() { ... });
```

if you use jQuery.

or if in case of pure javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
});
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: Added code (Just placed the script tag before body ends)

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" />
  <head>

<style>
  #text{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
}
  body{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hover over me to get a random color!</h1>
   <div id="text">Hex code</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById('text'),
    randomColor = function(e) {
    var hex = Math.floor( Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF ),
      res = e.target,
      result = "#" + hex.toString(16);
    res.style.backgroundColor = result;
    res.innerHTML = result;
  };
 div.addEventListener('mouseover', randomColor);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQuery just needs `$(function() { ... });` the `ready()` method is very legacy.

Comment: @Soviut I don't want Jquery, I want vanilla Javacript.

Comment: @T.Bragg I wasn't encouraging jQuery, I was just explaining that the jQuery example was outdated.